# Does current English law allow for a regional elected deputy mayor?

Tags: united-kingdom, local-government

> I will absorb the post into the West Midlands Combined Authority as an elected deputy mayor.

-- [Jon Hunt, candidate for West Midlands Police and Crime Commissioner](http://archive.today/2021.04.23-135109/https://www.choosemypcc.org.uk/candidates/west-midlands/jon-hunt/)

I'm pretty sure this wouldn't be in *his* gift :-). The full manifesto says he has a "plan", and the Liberal Democrats will work to achieve this goal.

This would require new primary legislation, right? I assume that's why I can't find further detail of this plan :-).

Or is there a provision for this elected deputy mayor role in the law (as of 2021)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - the post could be replaced by an *appointed* deputy mayor, but only with the consent of the Home Secretary, the mayor of the combined authority, the combined authority itself, and every county and district council within the combined authority.

Police and Crime Commissioners were introduced by the [Police Reform and Social Responsibility Act 2011](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/13/contents/enacted), which states:

> There is to be a police and crime commissioner for each police area
> listed in Schedule 1 to the Police Act 1996 (police areas outside
> London).

Within London there were separate provisions, including the establishment of The Mayor’s Office for Policing and Crime, occupied by the Mayor of London, with similar powers to the PCC. It also has the ability to delegate these powers to an appointed Deputy Mayor.

Later, the [Cities and Local Government Devolution Act 2016](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/1/contents/enacted) amended the [Local Democracy, Economic Development and Construction Act 2009](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2009/20/contents), adding [Section 107F](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2009/20/section/107F), allowing the Home Secretary to transfer the role of PCC to the mayor of a combined authority.

> The Secretary of State may by order provide for the mayor for the
> area of a combined authority to exercise functions of a police and
> crime commissioner in relation to that area.

This order must also abolish the position of PCC for that combined authority. However, this action may only be taken with the consent of the "appropriate authorities" (defined in [107B(5)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2009/20/section/107B)), as well as the current mayor of the combined authority.

Once this step has been taken, the Secretary of State may make another order under the provisions of Section 3 of [Schedule 5C](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2009/20/schedule/5C) of the 2009 Act:

> The Secretary of State must by order make provision authorising the
> mayor—
>
> - (a) to appoint a deputy mayor in respect of PCC functions (“deputy
>   mayor for policing and crime”), and
> - (b) to arrange for the deputy mayor for policing and crime to exercise
>   any PCC functions of the mayor.

So no, the PCC themselves doesn't actually have any say in the matter, and they certainly can't abolish the post unilaterally. They could, of course, put pressure on the mayor and the Secretary of State to absorb the functions of the role as described above, but the resultant deputy mayor for policing and crime would be appointed, not elected. This post currently exists in the Greater Manchester Combined Authority.